# Distribution of polymer components

Tags: dart, polymer

We have an application written entirely dart/polymer with quite a few polymer components. We use the custom tags in out index.html and compile to dart with pub build. The compile to javascript creates index.html of 24K lines. Original index.html is 150. The application works perfectly.

However we would like to distribute the code to third party sites so that they also can use the components with custom tags. Ideally by just linking to an already compiled script and simple using our custom tags in their pages.
I know this is possible without polymer. Question is does polymer support this? Is it possible to compile a polymer app and keep to a minimum amount of changes in the html file?

To reduce the problem to an example:
We would like our customers to be able to do some thing like this, without the use of dart sdk:

```
<head>
    <script src="what_ever_required.js"></script>
    <script src="our_application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <our-custom-tag></our-customer-tag>
    <p>What ever else content</p>
</body>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not supported.

Currently an application that used Dart code needs to be compiled to JS as a whole at once. There is no way to build parts of a Dart application and compose an application from them later.

With the upcoming DDC (Dart Development Compiler) there might be a way to accomplish that. An experimental approach is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymerize

Comment: Thank you. Possibly using polymer dart was a mistake. 

Note that we already create and distribute components similar to what I have described above by just manipulation of the DOM in dart code, without using Polymer or web components. However using ready made ui components in polymer would have been nice.

Comment: That's a main advantage of JS Polymer components. That's a limitation of the Dart language. I'm sure they will address this with DDC but no idea how long it will take.